# Can someone explain how these angles are equivalent?

Tags: geometry, vectors, congruences-geometry

Linked [here](http://www.farmingdale.edu/faculty/peter-nolan/pdf/relativity/Ch04Rel.pdf) is a great tutorial I've been reading on contravariant and covariant representations of vectors. I'm following along well up until page 5 and 6. Here, I'd like to know why in Figure 4.7(a), the angle created between $\bf r$ and the new axis $x_1$ is equivalent to $\alpha$.

[image]

Further, on page 6, it's stated that, from Figure 4.7, $x_1 = x^1 + x^2\cos\alpha$ and $x_2 = x^2 + x^1\cos\alpha$. Can someone break those assumptions down?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I should've done that for brevity. My bad.

Comment: First you find the $2$ lines that connect $\mathbf r$ with $x^1,x^2$ and create $90^°$ angle. Why $90$? Because it is easy to work with. Now we get a little shape. Set the lines we created for the new shape as the new axis, now you can work out the angle they created with one another and see it is $\alpha$

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor it is easy to prove it, there is enough information, look at my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know why in Figure 4.7(a), the angle created between $\bf r$ and the new axis $x_1$ is equivalent to $\alpha$.

It hinges on the fact that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$. If you know that, then all you need to know is that all the angles in a triangle sum to $180º$ in order to conclude that the two angles $\alpha$ are in fact congruent.

Remember that the goal was to devise a coordinate system in which ${\bf e}^1\perp{\bf a}_2$ (as stated in the first sentence on p. 4-5). Looking at the diagram, it appears that the coordinate system was designed such that that ${\bf a}^1\parallel{\bf e}^1$, which therefore implies that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$.

In addition, Holo describes in the comment section a way to soundly conclude that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$:

> We know that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$. Look at the right part of the image, we know that $\bf{L_2e^2}\perp \bf x^1\implies {\bf a}^2 \perp {\bf a}_1$. We can show that this is the same from the other side of $\bf r$ and conclude that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$.

The diagram isn’t labeled for a geometer, so I will try my best to reference the image. For this, let $\rm O$ be the origin, let hats indicate angles and let me label “points” with the nearest symbol:

Standard trig gives us these:

$$\widehat{\mathrm{O}x_1\mathbf{L}_1} = 90º$$
$$\widehat{\mathrm{O}\mathbf{L}_1x_1} = \alpha$$
$$\widehat{\mathbf{a}_1\mathrm{O}\mathbf{a}^1} = 90º-\alpha$$

Our conclusion that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$ gives us

$$\widehat{\mathbf{a}^1\mathrm{O}\mathbf{a}_2}=90º$$

We are simply left to deduce that

$$\widehat{\mathbf{a}_1\mathrm{O}\mathbf{a}_2} = \widehat{\mathbf{a}^1\mathrm{O}\mathbf{a}_2} - \widehat{\mathbf{a}_1\mathrm{O}\mathbf{a}^1} = 90º - \left(90º-\alpha\right) = \alpha$$

---

> Further, on page 6, it's stated that, from Figure 4.7, $x_1 = x^1 + x^2\cos\alpha$ and $x_2 = x^2 + x^1\cos\alpha$.

In regard to your second concern, redirect your attention to figure 4.4:

[image: fig 4.4]

You can definitely see how, looking at the bottom-right right triangle and remembering that we’re dealing with parallel lines,

$$\begin{align}
(\text{adjacent leg}) &= (\text{hypotenuse})\cos\alpha \\
&= x^2 \cos \alpha \end{align}$$

which you then add to $x^1$ to get $x_1$. The same logic applies in calculating $x_2$.

Does that clear things up for you?

Comment: We k ow that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$. Look at the right part of the image, we know that $\bf{L_2e^2}\perp \bf x^1\implies {\bf a}^2 \perp {\bf a}_1$. we can show that this is the same from the other side of $\bf r$ and conclude that ${\bf a}^1 \perp {\bf a}_2$.

Comment: The second concern was explained perfectly. Thank you. I'm still kind of stuck on the alpha thing, though. Can it be figured out via alternate interior angles?

Comment: @Shocked Let me type up a deeper explanation about that.

Comment: @Shocked How is that? Try sketching and labeling if you need

Comment: Also @Shocked, if you feel that my answer adequately resolved your second concern, then consider expressing gratitude by upvoting $\ddot\smile$ or possibly even giving the $\color{green}{\checkmark}$